# Cannot load Shorturl gem (ruby ErrorLoad)

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm fairly new to Ruby and keep knocking my head against gems, but this latest puzzle has really got me stumped.

After using the gem install shorturl, I added the following headers to a file in my project:

```
require "rubygems"
require "shorturl"

class Controller < Autumn::Leaf
```

When I run the project I get the following error:

> myfile.rb:3 in `require': no such file to load -- shorturl (LoadError)

I'm not sure what other information would be useful, except that without the require the script is working.  I'm guessing I need to add the rubygems path to some variable, but I have no idea which.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run `gem environment` to see the environment that RubyGems is running in.  Under `GEM PATHS` should be listed the paths that RubyGems will search for gems.

Depending on if you installed the gem as root or not it will either be under somewhere like `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8` or somewhere within your home directory.  You can use `gem list -d shorturl` to find out where it is installed.  If where it is isn't listed in the `GEM PATHS` you will have to add it to the `GEM_PATH` environment variable. For example:

```
export "GEM_PATH=$GEM_PATH:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8"
```

if that works you then need to add it to somewhere like your `.bashrc` to ensure its always loaded.