# How to run Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

This is my first time using Ruby, I hope you can help me to run this example.
I've cloned [`cloud`](https://github.com/ninajansen/cloud) and [`cloud_examples`](https://github.com/ninajansen/cloud_examples) in two subdirectories of `~/learnRuby/`, and `gem install cloud`.

```
ruby -v   // ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [i486-linux]
gem list  // cloud(0.0.1), RubyInline (3.8.6), pdf-writer (1.1.8)
```

I added to the `.rb` a shebang `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` and execute permissions.
**Edit:** Also added `require 'rubygems'`

Now, when I try to run one of the examples I get:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': 
no such file to load -- cloud (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from ./gettysburg.rb:4
```

Please help me to get in the right direction, btw I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: Install instructions say to install `sudo gem install ninajansen-cloud`, which is not what you installed. Did you try installing `ninajansen-cloud`? I'd also try installing a more common gem and see if that works, in case it's a problem with your setup.

Comment: @Karl I tried but I got ERROR:  could not find gem ninajansen-cloud locally or in a repository.  I'm to try another gem to see if it works as you advise. Thanks

Comment: Practically no `gem install` worked for me ever but only `sudo gem install`. That's why I have `alias gem='sudo gem'` around. If you issue `ruby <scriptname>` you don't need to give execute permission, or `.rb`. And of course there is always `irb` to try out new things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had problems before when using the default Ubuntu ruby and trying to find installed gems.  Best solution I would suggest is using [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) to manage your ruby and gems instead, it takes a bit more to get setup but once done I've not had any problems with finding gems.

Alternatively look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445123/cannot-load-shorturl-gem-ruby-errorload/4445498#4445498) if you would prefer to stick to the default ruby.

Comment: thanks for the advise, I followed the install steps, type rvm | head -1, returns rvm is /usr/local/bin/rvm.  The instructions say if correct should return rvm is a function, instead.  Anywayz I can install it in a Mac or Win7, what would be my best option for installing as simple as possible?

Comment: I've never used Ruby on Windows and don't have a Mac so I don't know how easy it is to use on them, there seem to be a lot of Mac Rubyists though so I assume it's pretty easy.

I take it you installed RVM as root since it's in `/usr/local/bin`?  I'm just guessing but try changing `. "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` into `. "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"` and see if that loads it.

Comment: thank very much, now rvm return is a function, also installed in Win and Leopard, but I'm still having problems with the gem.  e.g. when I look inside cloud-0.0.1 I only see a Rakefile and readme.md.  Is this a problem with the gem? should I see the lib and content?

Comment: Just had a look on RubyGems.org and it seems the [`cloud` gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/cloud) is different to the `cloud` you've linked above.  The readme says to install `ninajansen-cloud` but I can't find that on RubyGems so I'm not sure where to install it from.  I'd suggest contacting ninajansen about it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `rubygems` before you include any other gems.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'cloud'

# code
```

Comment: The error message he posted says "gem_original_require", so apparently he did require rubygems first (also the examples he linked to require rubygems first thing as well).

Comment: @sepp2k Yes, I added it before, then I removed in the question, but now is edited including the require rubygems and the error msg